# why does $\sin(2\sin^{-1}{(x/2)}) = x\sqrt{1-x^2/2}$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

$$\sin\left(2\sin^{-1}{\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}\right) = x\sqrt{1-\frac{x^2}{2}}$$

I don't understand how to prove this statement.

Comment: $\sin^{-1}$ is $\csc$ or $\arcsin$ here?

Comment: here is arcsin-

Comment: @TPace $\sin^{-1}$ virtually always means $\arcsin$.

Comment: @NPLS I believe you mean the right-hand side to be $x\sqrt{1-(x/2)^2}$.

Comment: ohh yup my bad-

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$\sin(2u)=2\sin(u)\cos(u)=2\sin(u)\sqrt{1-\sin^2(u)}$$Let $u=\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)$
$$\sin\left(2\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\right)=2\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\sqrt{1-\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^2}$$

Comment: We need to show why $\cos u\ge0$

Answer (score 1):

$$
\begin{split}
\sin(2\sin^{-1}(x/2))&=2\sin(\sin^{-1}(x/2))\cos(\sin^{-1}(x/2))\\
&=x\cos(\sin^{-1}(x/2))\\
&=x\sqrt{1-\sin(\sin^{-1}(x/2))^2}\\
&=x\sqrt{1-\frac{x^2}4}
\end{split}
$$